# Android - not able to access onDraw()

Tags: android, xml, drawing

I have to show a resizable rectangle on an acivity.

My xml file:

```
 <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".exampleActivity">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/office"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/office"
android:src="@raw/office" />

<com.lambdahash.sonic.example.draw.DrawView
android:id="@+id/drawView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code to display the Rectangle on this activity:

```
public class DrawView extends View {

    Point point1, point3;
    Point point2, point4;

    /**
     * point1 and point 3 are of same group and same as point 2 and point4
     */
    int groupId = -1;
    private ArrayList<ColorBall> colorballs = new ArrayList<ColorBall>();
    // array that holds the balls
    private int balID = 0;
    // variable to know what ball is being dragged
    Paint paint;
    Canvas canvas;

    public DrawView(Context context) {

        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
        canvas = new Canvas();

       // this.setWillNotDraw(false); //?

        Log.d("TEST:","DrawView() being called.");

        // setting the start point for the balls
        point1 = new Point();
        point1.x = 50;
        point1.y = 20;

        point2 = new Point();
        point2.x = 150;
        point2.y = 20;

        point3 = new Point();
        point3.x = 150;
        point3.y = 120;

        point4 = new Point();
        point4.x = 50;
        point4.y = 120;

        // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point1));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point2));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point3));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point4));

    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        paint = new Paint();
        setFocusable(true); // necessary for getting the touch events
        canvas = new Canvas();
        // setting the start point for the balls
        point1 = new Point();
        point1.x = 50;
        point1.y = 20;

        point2 = new Point();
        point2.x = 150;
        point2.y = 20;

        point3 = new Point();
        point3.x = 150;
        point3.y = 120;

        point4 = new Point();
        point4.x = 50;
        point4.y = 120;



        // declare each ball with the ColorBall class
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point1));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point2));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point3));
        colorballs.add(new ColorBall(context, R.drawable.gray_circle, point4));

    }

    // the method that draws the balls
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        Log.d("TEST:","onDraw() being called.");

        // canvas.drawColor(0xFFCCCCCC); //if you want another background color

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55000000"));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        // mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#55FFFFFF"));

        if (groupId == 1) {
            canvas.drawRect(point1.x + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                    point3.y + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point3.x
                            + colorballs.get(2).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point1.y
                            + colorballs.get(0).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);
        } else {
            canvas.drawRect(point2.x + colorballs.get(1).getWidthOfBall() / 2,
                    point4.y + colorballs.get(3).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point4.x
                            + colorballs.get(3).getWidthOfBall() / 2, point2.y
                            + colorballs.get(1).getWidthOfBall() / 2, paint);
        }
        BitmapDrawable mBitmap;
        mBitmap = new BitmapDrawable();

        // draw the balls on the canvas
        for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
            canvas.drawBitmap(ball.getBitmap(), ball.getX(), ball.getY(),
                    new Paint());
        }
    }

    //??????????????????
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {


        Log.d("TEST2:","onMeasure() being called.");

        Log.v("Chart onMeasure w", MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
        Log.v("Chart onMeasure h", MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));

        int desiredWidth = getSuggestedMinimumWidth() + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        int desiredHeight = getSuggestedMinimumHeight() + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        setMeasuredDimension(measureDimension(desiredWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
                measureDimension(desiredHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    private int measureDimension(int desiredSize, int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            result = desiredSize;
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }

        if (result < desiredSize){
            Log.e("ChartView", "The view is too small, the content might get cut");
        }
        return result;
    }




    // events when touching the screen
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int eventaction = event.getAction();

        int X = (int) event.getX();
        int Y = (int) event.getY();

        switch (eventaction) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // touch down so check if the finger is on
                // a ball
                balID = -1;
                groupId = -1;
                for (ColorBall ball : colorballs) {
                    // check if inside the bounds of the ball (circle)
                    // get the center for the ball
                    //Utils.logd("Id : " + ball.getID());
                    //Utils.logd("getX : " + ball.getX() + " getY() : " + ball.getY());
                    int centerX = ball.getX() + ball.getWidthOfBall();
                    int centerY = ball.getY() + ball.getHeightOfBall();
                    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                    // calculate the radius from the touch to the center of the ball
                    double radCircle = Math
                            .sqrt((double) (((centerX - X) * (centerX - X)) + (centerY - Y)
                                    * (centerY - Y)));

                    //Utils.logd("X : " + X + " Y : " + Y + " centerX : " + centerX + " CenterY : " + centerY + " radCircle : " + radCircle);

                    if (radCircle < ball.getWidthOfBall()) {

                        balID = ball.getID();
                        //Utils.logd("Selected ball : " + balID);
                        if (balID == 1 || balID == 3) {
                            groupId = 2;
                            canvas.drawRect(point1.x, point3.y, point3.x, point1.y,
                                    paint);
                        } else {
                            groupId = 1;
                            canvas.drawRect(point2.x, point4.y, point4.x, point2.y,
                                    paint);
                        }
                        invalidate();
                        break;
                    }
                    invalidate();
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // touch drag with the ball
                // move the balls the same as the finger
                if (balID > -1) {
                    //Utils.logd("Moving Ball : " + balID);


                    Log.d("Moving Ball : " ,"" + balID);

                    colorballs.get(balID).setX(X);
                    colorballs.get(balID).setY(Y);

                    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);

                    if (groupId == 1) {
                        colorballs.get(1).setX(colorballs.get(0).getX());
                        colorballs.get(1).setY(colorballs.get(2).getY());
                        colorballs.get(3).setX(colorballs.get(2).getX());
                        colorballs.get(3).setY(colorballs.get(0).getY());
                        canvas.drawRect(point1.x, point3.y, point3.x, point1.y,
                                paint);
                    } else {
                        colorballs.get(0).setX(colorballs.get(1).getX());
                        colorballs.get(0).setY(colorballs.get(3).getY());
                        colorballs.get(2).setX(colorballs.get(3).getX());
                        colorballs.get(2).setY(colorballs.get(1).getY());
                        canvas.drawRect(point2.x, point4.y, point4.x, point2.y,
                                paint);
                    }

                    invalidate();
                }

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // touch drop - just do things here after dropping

                break;
        }
        // redraw the canvas
        invalidate();
        return true;

    }

    public void shade_region_between_points() {
        canvas.drawRect(point1.x, point3.y, point3.x, point1.y, paint);
    }
}
```

And, finally invoking this on the activity.xml using this:

```
public class exampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);


       DrawView dv = new DrawView(getApplicationContext());


    }
```

So, when I'am invoking the myDrawView in onCreate() in activity, I am getting,

`TEST: myDrawView() constructor called.`. But, after that I'am **not getting** `TEST: onDraw() method called.` 
the onDraw() method is not getting invoked for some reason.What should I do?

Comment: super.onDraw(canvas); still nothing. not working.

Comment: Add a breakpoint and see if it's entering the onDraw mathod

Comment: it is not enough just to create view for it to `Draw()`. You have to add it to the screen

Comment: You'll need to add your custom view through xml or programmatically to View hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing actually adding a MyDrawView to your UI.  It isn't in the layout you posted.  It isn't being added to the layout programatically.  Just creating the view doesn't display it.

Comment: How do I initiate both the activity.xml and the myDrawView() together in onCreate() ??

Comment: Normally you'd add the myDrawView to the layout.  You can add custom views to layouts.  Then you don't have to do it in onCreate.  If you want to do it programatically for some reason, you need to add it to the parent with the proper layout params for the size and location you wish it in.  Also, you wouldn't use the Application context for a view-  you use the Activity context.  Views belong to an activity, they won't display using application context.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you didn't add your custom view neither in your layout file or in your  Activity code.
Try adding it like this.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".exampleActivity"
>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/office"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/office"
        android:src="@raw/office" 
    />

    <your.package.name.MyDrawView
        android:id="@+id/myAwesomeDrawView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" 
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then it should be displaying in your app.

Note, that as @GabeSechan [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52961936/android-not-able-to-access-ondraw/52962310#comment92832399_52962310), some containers wont lay out the view when it's measuring itself to have width and height of 0. You'll have to either specify your view's dimensions in the xml layout file or provide a [correct](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d) `onMeasure()`.

If you still want to add it programmatically, then you can do it in the `onCreate()` method, for example like this:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final RelativeLayout myAwesomeLayout = findViewById(R.id.your_container_id);
    final View myAwesomeView = new View(this);
    someViewsetLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    myAwesomeLayout.addView(myAwesomeView);
}
```

Please note, that convention is that class names are started with a capital letter in Java.

Some additional points:

- It seems like you're allocating a lot of objects in your `onDraw()`
  method, it may lead to increased memory consumption and poor
  performance, it's better to avoid this and to try and reuse objects
  instead of creating new ones.
- Your custom view constructors behave differently and contain duplicate code, it might be a good idea to move common initialization code to avoid code duplication, you can try doing it like this

```java
    public class MyDrawView extends View {

        // for example only
        @ColorInt final int fillColor;

        public MyDrawView(final Context context) {
            this(context, null);
        }

        public MyDrawView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public MyDrawView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);

            // initialize here, like
            fillColor = Color.parseInt("something");
        }
    }
```

Comment: getting no errors but still not able to reach onDraw() logs, look at my updated code, even onMeasure() being called.

Comment: Not sure, what the problem is. Although, `onMeasure()` looks kinda out of place.
The best thing I can suggest is to start with a minimal working example and then work your way up.
These links might be a good start for you: [on custom views](https://proandroiddev.com/android-draw-a-custom-view-ef79fe2ff54b) [onMeasure](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784d),

Comment: @MikhailOlshanski onMeasure could be the problem.  You gave it wrap_content width and height, if his onMeasure decides its width or height is 0, then it would be a 0 height/width view.  That may not get laid out by its parent.

Comment: @GabeSechan I agree, I might've mistaken in my example layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageView android:id="@+id/office"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:contentDescription="@string/office" android:src="@raw/office" />
```

Could this be a spelling error? Is that supposed to be @draw/office?